# Objective-C inheritence should change variables in superclass

Tags: objective-c, ios, macos, inheritance

I want to create a class hierarchy something like this:
AbstractBaseClass - > SubClass1, AbstractBaseClass -> subClass2
The abstract base class should have 2 instance variables (type id?) and setters and getter for thous variables ... the thing is that the variables in subclass 1 need to be of tpye NSNumber and NSSTring , and in the other subclass both will be NSNumber... Do I just inherit the base class and overwrite the setters and getters to cast NSNumber to the id of the super-class?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you create `id` type properties in the base class, you should be able to use them to store any type of object without doing anything extra in the subclasses.

Somewhat weird example:  :)

```
// Base class .h
@interface BaseClass : NSObject
@property (nonatomic, strong) id something;
@end

// Sub class .m
- (id)init {
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        BOOL test = (random() > random());
        if (test) {
            [self setValue:@"A string" forKey:@"something"];
        } else {
            [self setValue:@42 forKey:@"something"];
        }
    }
    return self;
}

// Caller
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    SubClass *sub = [[SubClass alloc] init];
    NSLog(@"Subclass result: %@", sub.something);
}
```

Comment: but when I use the subclass how can I be sure that the object get set correctly .. this must be KVC compliant

Comment: I don't understand what you think might get set incorrectly.   An `id` is the address of an object.  If you assign `NSNumber *` or `NSString *` those are both object addresses.